# rails 3 undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nomethoderror

i am making a sorting table in rails and getting an error. 
This is my index.html.erb

```
<table>  
  <tr>  
    <th><%= sortable "name" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "city" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "country" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "street_address" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "sector" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "telephone" %></th>
    <th><%= sortable "fax" %></th>
  </tr>  

  <% for company in @companies %>  
  <tr>  
    <td><%= company.name %></td>
    <td><%= company.city %></td>
    <td><%= company.country %></td>
    <td><%= company.street_address %></td>
    <td><%= company.sector %></td>
    <td><%= company.telephone %></td>
    <td><%= company.fax %></td>
  </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

This is my companies_controller

```
def index
  @companies = Company.order(params[:sort] + ' ' + params[:direction])
end
```

This is my application_helper

```
def sortable(column, title = nil)  
    title ||= column.titleize  
    direction = (column == params[:sort] && params[:direction] == "asc") ? "desc" : "asc"  
    link_to title, :sort => column, :direction => direction  
end
```

And the error is:

```
NoMethodError in CompaniesController#index

undefined method `+' for nil:NilClass
app/controllers/companies_controller.rb:21:in `index'
```

What is the problem and how can i fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `params[:sort]` returns `nil`.

You can fix it for example by checking your params:

```
@companies = Company.scoped
if params[:sort].present? && params[:direction].present?
  @companies = @companies.order(params[:sort] + ' ' + params[:direction])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `params[:sort]` is `nil`, so you'd better do:

```
def index
  @companies = params[:sort].blank? || params[:direction].blank? ? Company.scoped : Company.order(params[:sort] + ' ' + params[:direction])
end
```

Comment: Will throw "undefined method `each` for `nil`".

Comment: @badal what request do you make? And what is your view?

Comment: @RajarshiDas after your edit, it will still throw this error. In fact it changes nothing.

Comment: @RajarshiDas it should be `scoped` or `all` instead of `scope`. Now it throws `wrong number of arguments` error.

Comment: @RajarshiDas now it's okay.

Comment: @RajarshiDas it's still bad, BTW. There should be `||` operator instead of `&&`.

Comment: @MarekLipka in my view I check `<% unless @companies.empty? %>`

Comment: @badal Are you sure that this is the only thing you change? 
`nil.empty?` throws an error. 
@RajarshiDas it is ok now.

Comment: @MarekLipka in my view I check sorry not empty it nil `<% unless @companies.nil?  %>`

Comment: what is going on here?